# MySQL Left Join

Tags: mysql, wordpress, left-join

I have 2 tables (Wordpress Database), one which stores posts and the other post meta. For this example, the posts table is storing information about venues (i.e. bars or clubs). The meta table is storing a rating given to these bars by users/visitors. Ratings are stored as either 20, 40, 60, 80 or 100 under the key '_rating'. I have the following query.

```
SELECT posts.*, AVG(meta.meta_value) as average 
FROM wp_posts as posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as meta 
     ON posts.ID = meta.post_ID 

WHERE meta.meta_key = '_rating' 
     AND posts.post_status = 'publish' 
     AND posts.post_type = 'npc_venue' 

GROUP BY meta.post_id 
ORDER BY post_title asc
```

This works great except for one issue. If a venue has not yet received a rating, then there is no '_rating' entry in the wp_postmeta table, and thus it is not pulled in the query.

Question is: How can I pull all venues from the database, with their average rating, even when they have not yet received a rating. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: If a venue has not been rated yet, then there is no _rating entry in the wp_postmeta table, which brings up the question, what does NULL mean exactly? NULL is typically used for an unknown value. However, when the entry is missing completely from the table, is it still considered NULL? Or does it just become an empty rowset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `meta.meta_key = '_rating'` in the join condition, not in the `WHERE` clause, i.e. (untested):

```
SELECT posts.*, AVG(meta.meta_value) as average 
FROM wp_posts as posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as meta 
     ON posts.ID = meta.post_ID
    AND meta.meta_key = '_rating'

WHERE posts.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND posts.post_type = 'npc_venue' 

GROUP BY posts.ID 
ORDER BY post_title asc
```

Also note the change in the `GROUP BY` clause; if there are no matching metadata records, `meta.post_ID` will be NULL.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that works if there is no _rating key present for a venue!

Answer (score 1):

try something like ...

```
    SELECT posts.*,
    (SELECT AVG(meta.meta_value)
        FROM wp_postmeta as meta
        WHERE posts.ID = meta.post_ID
            AND meta.meta_key = '_rating' 
            AND posts.post_status = 'publish' 
            AND posts.post_type = 'npc_venue) as average
    ORDER BY post_title ASC
```

... not sure if this will work as-is, but the idea is there... make "average" a calculated field rather than a join.

Comment: This actually works when tweaked to include all of the components in the query. I am testing out some shorter solutions to see if they work now, but if not, yours solution is a winner!

Answer (score 0):

To count all non-rated venues you can use `ISNULL` function

```
SELECT posts.*, AVG(ISNULL(meta.meta_value, 0)) as average
```

Comment: This doesn't work because a NULL value is not the same as a non existent entry.

Comment: How can you describe not existing entry for rating? As far as I understand in case of not ranked venue its rating is not set, si is it meta.meta_value not set or..?

Comment: I've edited my initial answer, but still not sure whether you want simply to count all notn rated venues (this is makes sense to count them when all has a 0 value?) or just include all venues in final results set

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
SELECT posts.*, AVG(NULLIF(meta.meta_value,0)) as average
```

Comment: I like this option, but it doesn't seem to work. Check the edit in my post please.